# How to convert state dropdown to text box when country other than USA is selected in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in our application, we can have only 6 controls per row. 6 controls can be either text box or drop down or label what ever it might be. i am having city, state,zip and country fields where city and zip are text boxes. remaining two are drop downs. when country  USA is selected, i need city,state and zip to be required fields. when other than USA, state drop down needs to convert in to textbox and 3 textboxes should convert to optional fields. it should not fire error messages. i tried to hide and show textboxes based on country value. but we can have only 6 controls per row. as country is already there, we can have max of 5 controls but if i am replacing, then i need 6 controls. i am trying to do this only in angular js. it would be great if any one can help me?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Definitely need some code.  Seems like an arbitrary restriction to me.